# can't get high fps in SurfaceView on android

Tags: android, surfaceview

in my game thread i'm trying to get high fps- about 60
but only locking the canvas already make it 60 fps the most
this is the code i use-

```
public void run() 
{   
    super.run();
    int FPS = 60; 
                    final long TPF = 1000 / FPS;
    long startTime;
    long sleepTime;

    while (m_run)
    {   
        startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        m_canvas = m_surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        if (m_canvas != null)
        {            
        }
        m_surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(m_canvas);
        sleepTime = TPF - (SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime);
        Log.d("sleep", String.valueOf((SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime)));
    }
```

but only by calling `lockCanvas` and `unlockCanvasAndPost` i get that 60 ms has been over

Answer (score 3):

If you want a really high frame rate like 60fps, you probably need to use OpenGL instead of SurfaceView. You can still get a reasonable frame rate (eg. ~30fps) using SurfaceView with a low-to-moderate number of sprites drawn per frame, but I believe it's hard to do better than that without using OpenGL.

Note: your calls to 'Log.d' and 'String.valueOf' may slow down the frame rate noticeably themselves, which is an annoying catch-22.